# Facebook Ad Campaign Budget Update Fails

Tags: facebook, curl, response, facebook-ads-api

We are able to update ad campaign name using Facebook Ads API, but when we are trying to update any budget for the same campaign, we are getting "User request limit reached" error.

What may be the reason behind this?

Comment: It sounds like you're making too many API calls, how often are you updating the campaign budget? Is the error code 17?

Comment: @igy yes it is code 17. and the problem, is we are still able to update campaign name after this "limit reach", this error only occurs when we are updating budget. but if it was really a request limit, we should not be able to update campaign name too.

Comment: No, the error refers to making too many campaign budget changes, you can supply other fields to be edited more frequently, other than the budget related parameters. Campaign or account budget changes are an extremely expensive operation on the Facebook side, don't do it unless absolutely necessary, i'm unsure what the hard limit is but a 3-4 times a day per campaign should be OK I think

Answer (score 1):

The recently updated [API Rate Limiting Documentation](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/api-rate-limiting/#adcampaignlimit)  specifically mentions that changes to campaign daily budget and lifetime budget have their own rate limits, and that if you exceed them you'll receive the 'User request limit reached' error.

It doesn't give exact numbers as to what the specific limits are, though.